# Logback Logger name globbing for jUnit specific logger

Tags: logging, configuration, junit, logback

I'm using Spring with SLF4J and Logback.
Logger is automatically injected into bean using custom annotation and a `BeanPostProcessor`.

Is there a way to configure logger in logback.xml so that it's name is an expression of some kind? Something like Ant wildcards? This would help me configure a logger specifically for jUnit tests.

What I'm aiming for is something to the effect of:

```
<logger name="my.package.**.*Test">
    ...
</logger>
```

I'm open to better suited solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that is possible by default.  Hard to tell for sure as the logback documentation isn't written in a way that doesn't make it easy to look up stuff quickly.  It's written in a, hey you want to use logback, okay well how about reading for 45 minutes kinda way.

Anyway, you can probably do this if you **implement a custom LoggerFactory** (implement **org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory**) and tell logback to use your factory.

Answer (score 1):

This config suppresses all logs except except those whose logger name contains "Test".

```
<!-- Drops all logs except those from "Test" classes -->

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator>
            <expression>return logger.contains("Test");</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
    </filter>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```